# Rails TestCase UndefinedColumn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testcase

New to the rails world. Using 4.2.4.

I'm trying to create a model for my app and write some unit tests for it, but I'm running into difficulty after running a change migration. I created a model with

> rails generate model player first_name:string last_name:string dispaly_name:string

and ran `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`

Then I wrote a (failing) unit test to make sure the proper fields were set when calling save. At this point, I realized that I misspelled `dispaly_name`, so I created a change migration that fixed the column name.

Now when I try to run the unit test `rake test test/models/player_test.rb`, I get an error (`UndefinedColumn`) that says the save failed because the `Player` model is still trying to save with the `dispaly_name` instead of `display_name`. I ran `rake db:migrate` `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` `rake db:test:prepare` and ran `rails c` and `RAILS_ENV=test rails c` and checked that the column name was set properly by running `Player.column_names`. I also checked `schema.rb`. Everything seems to be in order, but I can't figure out why the `Player.new` in my test case is using the old column name.

Can someone explain what's happening?

Comment: Can you post the code in `test/models/player_test.rb` to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I got it:**

> when you create model then a fixture along with test file is created.

you created your model with field name `dispaly_name`, and in file `YourApp/test/fixtures/player_test.yml` a field `dispaly_name` is created. right?.

but the problem is that when you change field name to `display_name` it changes in `MODEL` and `TABLE` too but not in fixture file. so you need to correct your field in fixture file too.

**please change field name `dispaly_name` in file `YourApp/test/fixtures/player_test.yml`**

I hope it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon what you are using to populate your test db, **FactoryGirl**, **Fabrication** or the default **Fixtures** a Rails application come up with, change the data field name there. Then the error will disappear.

Do try restarting the server just in case if the error persists. I dont think so restarting the server will have any effect but just for a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `bundle exec rake:test:clone`, this recreates test db schema from current development one.

Comment: author has already run `db:test:prepare`, which does the same plus pending migrations on development